# How do I generate a pdf-file from a binary file?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, binaryfiles

How do I generate a pdf-file from a binary file retrieved from database in php5? It comes base64 encoded, and I just decoded it, but don't know what to do next...

Comment: What is a "binary file"? Do you mean you stored a PDF document base64 encoded in the database before?

Comment: I get the file from a webservice and I want to make it readable, but do not know in what way before I know my alternatives.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The binary data is simply *the actual file*, or rather the important contents of that file, just without file name.

```
$base64 = /* some base64 encoded data fetched from somewhere */;
$binary = base64_decode($base64);
```

And there you have the *file data/contents of the file* in the `$binary` variable. From here, it depends on what you want to do. You can write the data to a file, and you get an "actual" PDF file:

```
file_put_contents('my.pdf', $binary);
```

You can spit the data out to the browser with an appropriate header, and the user will receive something that looks like a PDF file to him:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my.pdf"');
echo $binary;
```

Comment: I usually don't thanks on SE sites... just up vote... but, after spending 2h trying to do this the "hard-way", and not finding any source for help ... I have to thank you! =D

Comment: Thanks so much! I was struggling with it, I didn't know the data I got was base64. When using base64_decode I finally got the PDF working. Another stress less!

Answer (score -1):

I'm repeating your last sentence .:) I dont know what is the question! :). If you want to pus the file to a browser, you can set the headers and stream the decoded content. Or if you want the file as is, write on to file system and use it. Please be more clear on your question!

Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry but this file-handling is new to me, so I'm trying to figure out how to use the pdf-file I'm fetching from the webservice that comes in a binary format.

Comment: @Kris I noticed your thumbnail quickly ! my old friend.

Comment: @Jobin OMG! And on a aged post ! Nice to meet you here :-)