# Restore and display PDF file from binary data on php page

Tags: php

I have a php page and I want to display a pdf which is stored in database as binary data.

Comment: header [ echo | print] [exit | die] where is your problem?

Comment: my problem is i don't know how to deal with the binary data and then display these data as pdf...

Comment: when it was an image i count assign it to DIV simply like that...
document.getElementById("Div_Cert_Image").src = "data:image/png;base64," + ImageData;

now i want the same for pdfs

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I generate a pdf-file from a binary file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006505/how-do-i-generate-a-pdf-file-from-a-binary-file)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a separate page that renders only the PDF.

Assuming your PDF binary data is stored in `$data`, you can do:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
echo $data;
```

...and you're done.
Note that to use `header()` you can't `echo` anything before it, otherwise it will be ignored and user will see random garbage instead of the file. That's why it's wise to make it a separate page dedicated to rendering files fetched from DB.

(If you need instructions on how to fetch binary data from your database, that's a material for another question. But before you ask it here, I suggest to search for this on the web first.)

Answer (score -1):

For me, as the file usually comes as a reasource from the DB, I do almost the exact same thing as rr- said, only instead of echo, I use fpassthru(), so my code looks like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
fpassthru($data);
```