# Download Binary content in SQL Server Using Php

Tags: php, pdf, sql-server-2012, binaryfiles

I'm using an .net app that can download pdf stored in a sql server DB. I found the source code and it looks like something like that :

```
        string mimeType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + docToDownload.TypeDocumentWorker + ".pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(file);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

I want to do the samething by using Php but , each time the file is corrupted (encrypted error from Adobe) . HEre's my simple code:

```
$filename = "yourfilename.pdf";
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public"); 
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
echo $row['file_in_DB'];
```

Any Help/Advices? I tried every tutorial or Similar question on Stack but each time i got a pdf file who cannot be openend neither by Browser or By Software (Adobe etc..)...

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563069/stream-binary-file-from-mysql-to-download-with-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006505/how-do-i-generate-a-pdf-file-from-a-binary-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate a pdf-file from a binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006505/how-do-i-generate-a-pdf-file-from-a-binary-file)

Comment: I tried every possible (at least i guess)  soluton on Stack and elsewhere , i just don't understand how imy code is actually not working ...